# PhonegapLog 1.4.1 bug on Android Tablets 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, Javascript execution exceeded timeout

Tags: jquery, android, cordova

I am getting an error if I want to use $.getJson("..").

```
Error Msg: Javascript execution exceeded timeout at file jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
```

This error is only on android tablet 3.0, 3.1, 3.2 devices.

What kind of error is it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the timeout of the getJSON call to a higher value?

```
    $.getJson({
    url: 'yourURL',
    timeout: 25000, // THIS IS THE TIMEOUT
    success: function() {

        });
    },
    error: function(){

    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks for reply, there was a really strange error, I get this error if I call the 1. January.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to $.ajax()

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://example.com",
      dataType: "json",
      timeout: 10000,
      success: function(data)
    });
```

exiting your app and then clear data...
Settings -> Manage applications -> then select your app -> clear data / clear cache

start up your app :)